# How to return 1st 2nd...nth not blank value from column and values from column before and after

Tags: excel

I have column B with numbers. I need to return those numbers in same order on separate sheet but skipping blank cells. In other words I need to copy everything to another sheet omitting blank rows and the rows with 0 values.

[image]

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/525-excel-remove-blank-rows.html#methoda ... this link gives you three options

Comment: thanks Tim for lightening fast answer but it did not serve my needs. I need to have Sheet1 intact but copy data to Sheet2 without blank cells. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your data implies that you want all this data on the same worksheet.  Regardless, you should still be able to make the options in the above link work.  Just copy sheet 1 to sheet 2, then strip off the completely blank rows.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks Tim for Your solution but it does not suit my needs. It will leave the rows with Item or Price present but blank/zero  Qty cell in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula. Then drag and drop to down and right as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$C$10,SMALL(IF($B$3:$B$10>0,ROW($B$3:$B$10)-ROW($B$2),""),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

You must press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after putting the formula into cell to evaluate it as array formula.

If you want to use this formula in another sheet then use following formula. Just add `Sheet1!` before reference range to use it in different sheet.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$C$10,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$10>0,ROW(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$10)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$2),""),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

Comment: Hi,Wow Harun24HR. That's exactly what I was looking for. Formula works perfectly. Was looking for this solution last 2 days with no joy and You did it in no time. Many thanks

Comment: If you found it working then you should accept `(Tick the answer as green)` the answer so that other visitor can see it is a useful answer.

Comment: @Daiva Why this comment here?

Comment: sorry I'm first time user, little bit wondering arround. Wanten to thank Tim for his solution but looks in wrong place.

Comment: cant find how to tick answer as green. I'm useless here

Comment: @Daiva Just left side of answer where you will see a Tick mark, one up arrow, one down arrow. Just click on that tick mark.

Comment: Thanks Harun. Best wishes to You.

Answer (score 0):

Or Filter and deselect `0` and `(Blanks)` from ColumnB, Copy and Paste.